# Disqus integration in website.. what is wrong?

Tags: html, website-design, web-development, javascript

I try to embed a disqus forum in a website I created. I used the exact code and instructions they give on the installation instructions. I just don't get it. Not much on Google either. Is something wrong in the code? Should I change anything?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
<title>Little Louie | Hennis &amp; Blaisse Lovers Productions</title> 
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="some,tags"> 
<link href="../style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
</head>

<body>

<p><b>Some text</p>
<p>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = 'http://littelouie.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript=littelouie">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>

</p>

<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_shortname = 'littelouie';
(function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
  s.src = 'http://disqus.com/forums/littelouie/count.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
}());
</script>

</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific, what actually happens? Can you give a link?

Comment: hi Claudiu.. somehow I have removed some lines and suddenly it appears to be working. The site is littlelouie.nl. I still have to make the container in which disqus is placed enlarge (the comments are now shown in a tiny scrollable area), but at least it is rendered now! This is my first website, so I am learning. Hope I can fix it. Thanks for your reply.